# Properties of a sequence $(s_n)$ such that $d(s_n,s_{n+1}) \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I have been reading George M. Bergman's supplementary notes and exercises to Rudin's *Introduction to mathematical analysis* (which can be found here https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_exs.pdf), and I am stuck in problem 3.2:6 part b), which states the following:

Let $X$ be a metric space and $(s_n)$ a sequence in $X$ such that $d(s_n,s_{n+1}) \rightarrow 0$. Let $E$ denote the subsequential limit set of $(s_n)$ (that is, $p\in E$ whenever there is a subsequence of $(s_n)$ which converges to $p$). Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, all but finitely many natural numbers $n$ have the property that there exists $p \in E$ such that $d(s_n,p)< \epsilon$. (I assume that one must suppose that $E$ is not empty, otherwise the proposition would be false).

Here is what I've tried:

If $S$ denotes the range of the sequence $(s_n)$, then we can split $S$ in two disjoint subsets: for some $\epsilon > 0$, define $A : = \{s_n \in S | \forall p \in E: d(s_n, p) \geq \epsilon\}$ and $B := \{s_n \in S | \exists p \in E: d(s_n, p) < \epsilon \}$. Clearly both sets are disjoint, $S = A \cup B$, and $B$ has infinitely many elements. I've tried to prove the statement by asumming that $A$ has infinitely many elements, and then conclude that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} d(s_n, s_{n+1}) \neq 0$, or assuming that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} d(s_n, s_{n+1}) = 0$ and then obtain a contradiction, but I see no way of getting to the desired result. Maybe the proposition is false, but I've not been able to figure out a counterexample.

I would be really grateful if you could help me to solve this problem, not with the complete answer, but with some hint, suggestion, or material that could be related to this.

Comment: How do we know $E$ is nonempty?

Comment: This seems wrong: assume that $0\leqslant s_n\leqslant1$ for every $n$ and that the limit set is $E=[0,1]$ (yes this is possible), then, for every $p$ in $E$, $d(s_n,p)>\frac13$ for infinitely many indices $n$.

Comment: @Did My reading is that $p$ is allowed to depend on $n$ (and $\epsilon$).

Comment: What if $X$ is two points $x,y$ joined by infinitely many isometrically embedded copies of $[0,1]$ (with distances between points on different segments being the maximal possible).  And then $s_n$ is the sequence which goes from $x$ to $y$ in 1 step, then from $y$ to $x$ along the second segment in 2 steps, then from $x$ to $y$ along the third segment in 3 steps, etc.  It seems that then we would have $E = \{ x, y \}$ but there are infinitely many $s_n$ at a distance greater than $\frac{1}{10}$ from $x$ or $y$.

Comment: Actually, I guess you don't need any particularly exotic $X$: in $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, define a sequence by appending finite subsequences where the $n$th goes along the line from $(0,0)$ to $(n,1)$ in $n^2$ steps and then back to $(0,0)$ in $n^2$ steps.  Then $E = [0, \infty) \times \{ 0 \}$ but infinitely many terms of the sequence are at a distance greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ from $E$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler  Thanks for your suggestion on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but don't you think that $E$ may have elements other than $(0,0)$? We should make it precise because as my intuition tells, some of the points of the sequence will accumulate in the region $C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \}$

Comment: @ZacharySelk It is a hypothesis that I think the author forgot to include.

Comment: @Did $p$ can depend on $n$.

Comment: I did realize that $E = [0, \infty) \times \{ 0 \}$.  The important part here is that $E \subseteq [0, \infty) \times \{ 0 \}$: if $y_0 > 0$, then the subsequence where $|(a_n)_2 - y_0| < \frac{1}{2} y_0$ has $x$ coordinates going to $\infty$ so it cannot have any finite $(x_0, y_0)$ as a subsequential limit.

Comment: I think the statement is true in the case $X = \mathbb{R}$ (in which case $E$ must be a closed interval, i.e. $[a,b]$, $[a, \infty)$, $(-\infty, b]$, or $(-\infty, \infty)$).

Comment: A construction similar to that of Daniel Schepler that should make clear that the claim is generally incorrect: Make 'roundtrips' from $(0,0)$ to $(0,n)$ to $(1,n)$ to $(1,0)$ and back to $(0,0)$ with points of distance $\frac1n$. Put those 'roundtrips' one after another, starting with $n=1$.
Then $E$ will not contain any point $(x,y)$ with  $y > 0, x \neq 0,1$, but infinitely many points $(x_i,y_i)$ of the sequence satisfy $\frac13 < x_0 < \frac23$ (those on the $(0,n)$ to $(1,n)$ part of each roundtrip) and are not in a small neighborhood of any point of $E$.

Comment: You are both right. Thank you.